# How to surely withdraw _everything_ from an ETH address?

Tags: ether, gas

I have some small amount of ethereum on one of the addresses and a perfectionist in me wants to move the whole amount to a different address, leaving exactly 0 ETH on this one. Is there a sure way to do it? To factors are unclear to me:

- When I specify an amount for transaction, would it be amount *before* the transaction fee (so I cannot take all the sum) or I just say “send all” and the fee will be automatically deducted from the amount arrived
- Gas price changes, so you cannot be sure about exact fee, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some wallets will do this for you, but if you want to manually do it here's how:

1. Select a gas price before-hand. Let's say you want to use 100 gwei.
2. An ETH transaction costs 21000 gas, so you'll use 21*10^14 (21000 * 100 * 1E9) wei for the transaction. This is 0.0021 ETH.
3. Subtract 0.0021 ETH from your total amount and send that in the transaction.

If you want to be extra sure, you can go to a testnet, send the amount you have to a new account, and then try this there and later check if there's 0 balance after the transaction.